# Device for preventing 12V battery from dying

Tags: protection, low-voltage, circuit-breaker

I am looking for a device which cuts off the connection between batteries and the system just like a circuit breaker when my 12V battery goes below 9V(for example) for preventing it from dying completely. I can use a comparator circuit and a power relay however wondering if something off the shelf can do the job.

Comment: One analog way is a self driven relay with excitation voltage at 9V . Additionally a power pfet with gate tied to ground can be configured or chosen  such that it will shut off if supply VDS drops below a certain threshold

Comment: Watch that relay solution. If its excitation voltage is 9V, its dropout voltage is likely to be about 4V, which won't be very good for the battery.

Comment: This concept is about half of a battery protection circuit for a Lithium-Ion cell (the other half is to prevent overvoltage on charging).  You could try Googling "battery protection circuit".  If what you're powering doesn't pull extreme currents (i.e., if it's not a car starter battery) then a mosfet driven with a reference and a comparator, instead of a relay, may work well.

Answer (score 1):

You did not indicate the current load, so here are a couple of alternatives.

The first possibility is an actual [battery-protection IC](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq76200.pdf), or you can coax a [high-side driver](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/NCV8450-D.PDF) or [power sequencing switch](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ISP742RI-DS-v01_01-en.pdf?folderId=db3a304412b407950112b408e8c90004&fileId=db3a304412b407950112b429555440bf&ack=t) to do the job. But you would still need to add some circuitry around any of them to make them work.

A second possibility is just a circuit with an adequate PMOS. There is quite a bit threshold variability and you would want something steeper than a gradual current reduction. Just adding a Zener might be enough. Here are a couple of ideas that should be refined somewhat before being put in practice.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7S8aB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

But you might want to add some hysteresis, so that the removal of consumption from your circuit does not turn the pass switch back on and you end up with a power oscillation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flyEco.png)</sup>

And of course, you could put together a similar circuit with a relay instead.